# How to use Chow Lin method?

Tags: data, data-mining

Can someone give me a simple explanation of how exactly this method works.

If I have a dataset of say 10 quarters (dependent variable);

- how should the independent variable (say monthly data) be aligned?
- What if the quarter ends in June 2010 for example and the independent (higher frequency data) ends in August 2010.

Comment: Please add reference to the model, preferably by including the formula in the question or at least by mentioning a reference paper.

Comment: The original Chow Lin 1971 paper here http://www.princeton.edu/~erp/ERParchives/archivepdfs/M124.pdf